# Favicon not in the right place?

Tags: html, css

I want the favicon to be in the centre but its going a little lower? the a href attribute is meant to add a link to the icon, by removing it the icon turns to the normal state, yet the code is the same for all of them? 
[img of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/422wX.jpg)

```
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
                          <a href="pensionr.html"<i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x text-primary" style=color:rgb(128,0,0);></i> <!--Blue Circle -->
                          <i class="fa fa-stack-overflow fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></a> <!--Icon inside -->
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h4>Pension Review</h4>
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>**strong text**
```

Comment: any css? you think we can help with just html?

Comment: The a tag is not closed before the i tag. You missed a '>' . Look below.

Answer (score 2):

Change this row:

```
<a href="pensionr.html"<i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x text-primary" style=color:rgb(128,0,0);></i> <!--Blue Circle -->
```

With this one:

```
<a href="pensionr.html"><i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x text-primary" style=color:rgb(128,0,0);></i> <!--Blue Circle -->
```

Cause you miss a > after pensionr.html"